# перегенерация ключа salt-minion

Tags: saltstack

наделано множество клонов виртуальной машины,
и, обнаружено, что все они работают с  одинаковым ключом -общим на всех.

т.е. salt-key -P показывает один и тот же pub Key

проблем оно вроде бы не вызывает,
но хотелось бы все сделать по-правильному.
Как перегенерировать ключи?

удаление 
/etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem
/etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pub
не решает проблему- ключ получается тот же

как сделать правильно?

Comment: вероятно, при клонировании стоит удалить из «образцового образа» файлы `/etc/salt/minion_id` (будет заполнен значением от команды `hostname`, которое, надеюсь, у вас уникально для каждого клона) и `/etc/salt/pki/minion/minion*` (должны быть сгенерированы при первом запуске *salt-minion*).

Answer (score 0):

у каждого *minion-а*, чтобы *master* мог их отличать, должен быть уникальный идентификатор, хранящийся на *minion-е* в файле `/etc/salt/minion_id`.

на *minion-е*:

1. остановите *salt-minion*:

   ```
   $ sudo service salt-minion stop
   ```
2. запишите подходящий уникальный идентификатор:

   ```
   $ echo уникальный-идентификатор | sudo tee /etc/salt/minion_id
   ```
3. удалите старый ключ:

   ```
   $ sudo rm /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pub
   ```
4. запустите *salt-minion* (при этом должен быть сгенерирован новый ключ вместо удалённого):

   ```
   $ sudo service salt-minion start
   ```

---

теперь *master-у* придёт новый запрос на подключение, который можно увидеть, например, такой командой (на *master-е*):

```
$ salt-key -l un
```

а затем подключить «стучашихся» *minion-ов*. всех сразу:

```
$ salt-key -A
```

или по одному:

```
$ salt-key -a идентификатор-minion-а
```

---

**дополнение**

чтобы убрать ненужные записи о *minion-ах* из конфигурации *master-а* (которые показывает программа *salt-key*), надо на *master-е* удалить соответствующие файлы из каталога `/etc/salt/pki/master/minions/`

Comment: да,  я находил такой рецепт в сети,
 
после указанных манипуляций по-прежнему salt-key -P
показывает все ключи одинаковыми,
при этом salt-key -F  показывает разные fingerprint
кому верить?

Comment: @tester0, см. дополнение к ответу.